# Equivalent to the ViM :smile command

Tags: commands

In ViM, there is a `:smile` command that displays lighthearted ASCII graphics of a figure that smiles.

Is there an equivalent command available in Emacs?

Comment: Not exactly, but there are `M-x butterfly`, `M-x doctor`, `M-x gomoku` and few other lighthearted commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not too tricky to do yourself:

```
(defun smile ()
  "Smile at you.

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/equivalent-to-the-vim-smile-command"
  (interactive)
  (with-help-window "*smile*"
    (princ "                            oooo$$$$$$$$$$$$oooo
                        oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o
                     oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o         o$   $$ o$
     o $ oo        o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o       $$ $$ $$o$
  oo $ $ \"$      o$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$o       $$$o$$o$
  \"$$$$$$o$     o$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$o    $$$$$$$$
    $$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$  \"\"\"$$$
     \"$$$\"\"\"\"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     \"$$$
      $$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     \"$$$o
     o$$\"   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$       $$$o
     $$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\" \"$$$$$$ooooo$$$$o
    o$$$oooo$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    $$$$$$$$\"$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"
   \"\"\"\"       $$$$    \"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\"      o$$$
              \"$$$o     \"\"\"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\"$$\"         $$$
                $$$o          \"$$\"\"$$$$$$\"\"\"\"           o$$$
                 $$$$o                                o$$$\"
                  \"$$$$o      o$$$$$$o\"$$$$o        o$$$$
                    \"$$$$$oo     \"\"$$$$o$$$$$o   o$$$$\"\"
                       \"\"$$$$$oooo  \"$$$o$$$$$$$$$\"\"\"
                          \"\"$$$$$$$oo $$$$$$$$$$
                                  \"\"\"\"$$$$$$$$$$$
                                      $$$$$$$$$$$$
                                       $$$$$$$$$$\"
                                        \"$$$\"\"\"\"
")))
```

Comment: To format code, select it and press Ctrl+K (or click the `{}` button above the editor).